# tensorflow bazel building fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

building `tf` (following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#prepare_environment_for_linux))

`./configure && bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` fails:

```
root@commandor:/opt/tf/sc/tensorflow# bazel build --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
WARNING: /home/ertosns/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/502c46fd2b7f9ff136e0381cc7e075fe/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /home/ertosns/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/502c46fd2b7f9ff136e0381cc7e075fe/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions
ERROR: /home/ertosns/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/502c46fd2b7f9ff136e0381cc7e075fe/external/jpeg/BUILD:126:12: Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "deps" in @jpeg//:jpeg:
@jpeg//:k8
@jpeg//:armeabi-v7a
Multiple matches are not allowed unless one is unambiguously more specialized.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: 

/home/ertosns/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/502c46fd2b7f9ff136e0381cc7e075fe/external/jpeg/BUILD:126:12: Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "deps" in @jpeg//:jpeg:
@jpeg//:k8
@jpeg//:armeabi-v7a
Multiple matches are not allowed unless one is unambiguously more specialized.
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.065s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (97 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/contrib/data/kernels ... (3 packages)
```

not well acquainted with bazel, but according to [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) condition argument targeting jpeg need to be passed, what argument exactly, why the guide didn't mention that?

building version r1.6 under python 2.7, 3.6 both fail with the same error.

configuration process: refusing all support except for jemalloc.

```
root@commandor:/opt/tf/sc/tensorflow# ./configure 
You have bazel 0.12.0 installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: 


Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with jemalloc as malloc support? [Y/n]: y
jemalloc as malloc support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [Y/n]: n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [Y/n]: n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Amazon S3 File System support? [Y/n]: n
No Amazon S3 File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Apache Kafka Platform support? [y/N]: n
No Apache Kafka Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]: n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GDR support? [y/N]: n
No GDR support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]: n
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL SYCL support? [y/N]: n
No OpenCL SYCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]: n
No MPI support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 


Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: n
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See tools/bazel.rc for more details.
    --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
    --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
    --config=tensorrt       # Build with TensorRT support.
Configuration finished
```

I'm trying to build the source, because after uninstalling tensorflow, and reinstalling it, it didn't work! although it was working in previous version, on ubuntu 17.xx, current ubuntu version is 17.10 artful

google groups [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/pULf_ytbdM4)

[my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805375/tensorflow-on-ubuntu-17-10-artful-fails) on the same subject, but for different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the 0.12 version of bazel cause the problem, try to downgrade it to 0.11.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, with Bazel 0.12, going back to Bazel 0.11 worked form me:

```
$ curl -LO "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.11.1/bazel_0.11.1-linux-x86_64.deb" 

$ sudo dpkg -i bazel_*.deb
```